# Authorization Required You must first log in or register before accessing this page. If you have forgotten your password salesforce

Tags: salesforce

> I have setup a site but when i am opening this site i am getting this
> type error,   Authorization Required
>
> You must first log in or register before accessing this page. If you
> have forgotten your password, click Forgot Password to reset it.

[click and check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGl6G.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the visualforce page which you created has access to Guest user profile. To navigate to Guest user, do as below:

Go to Setup -> Develop -> Sites -> Click Site name -> Public Access Settings

Comment: In this just make sure you add your Visualforce page under Enabled Visualforce Page Access related list section. Also make sure if you have any object, fields exposed via Visualforce page are accessible by this profile.

Comment: Yes my Visualforce page in available under Enabled Visualforce Page Access.
There is any issue with this url ?
<apex:page action="{!URLFOR('/answers/answersHome.apexp')}"/>

Comment: I have setup default page(AnswersHome)for testing, i am new in salesforce please help me to figureout this problem please

Comment: please help me on this

Comment: I am using it in testing mode

Comment: Have you sorted it out? I am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The sites under **Digital Experiences / All sites** are called Experience Cloud sites.
The sites under **Sites and Domains > Sites** are called Salesforce sites.
These are different categories of sites and they come with different behaviors.

Based on the screenshot you shared with me, (the url has force.com included), it looks like your site is in the second category, please be aware of that:
Users from the Salesforce sites can only see their own data. If your program is trying to access data recreated by other, you will get the Authorization Required error.

As a way to test this, try to comment out the SOQL statements, the error message may go away.

also check out the following link:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_networks_guest_user.htm&type=5&release=228

The Secure guest user record access setting was enabled in Summer ’20, but could still be disabled during that release. To safeguard your Salesforce org’s data, in Winter ’21, this setting is enabled in all orgs with communities or sites and can't be disabled. **The Secure guest user record access setting enforces private org-wide defaults for guest users** and requires that you use guest user sharing rules to open up record access. You also can't add guest users to groups or queues or grant guest users record access through manual sharing or Apex managed sharing.